# Сохранение переменной типа String с символами переноса строки в текстовый файл как одну строку

Tags: java

Я записываю файл построчно из массива, каждая строка файла в итоге это элемент массива

```
// запись массива в файл
public static void recordFile(String fileName, String[] currentMassive) {
    try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fileName, false)) {
        for (int count = 0; count < currentMassive.length; count++) {
            writer.write(currentMassive[count]);
            writer.append('\n');
        }
        writer.flush();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Суть проблемы: к примеру элемент массива имеет следующее содержимое

*currentMassive[count] = "1\n2\n3";*

После сохранения в файл получается следующий результат:

```
...
информация count-2
информация count-1
1
2
3
информация count+1
...
```

А я же рассчитывал получить результат в виде

```
...
информация count-2
информация count-1
1*СПС*2*СПС*3
информация count+1
...
```

где *СПС* - символ переноса строки

Вопрос: Как/(возможно ли) сохранить переменную типа String, а именно элемент массива, в текстовый файл как одну строку с сохранением символов переноса строки?

Спасибо.

Comment: Только если действительно вместо перевода строки вы будете писать в файл два символа: `\ ` и `n`.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, тут нужно вместо:

```
writer.write(currentMassive[count]);
```

Написать:

`writer.write(currentMassive[count].Replace("\\n",""));`

Т.е. надо просто удалить из строки `\n`, что мешает, и записать новую строку в файл.